# Soundflower with FireWire soundcard transmits on all output channels

Tags: macos, mac, audio, sound-card

when I try to use Soundflower together with my external 12ch FireWire sound card on a MacBook Pro, I get the same signal (left and right channel combined) on all of the output channels. If you know about Soundflower and how it works, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or leads to where the problem might reside.

Here's what I do:

1. In the MacBook's Sound preferences, select Soundflower 2ch for output
2. In the Soundflowerbed menu, select the Firewire soundcard for output
3. In the Soundflowerbed menu, make sure that Soundflower Channel 1(2) maps to channel 1(2) on the soundcard, and that "Clone to all channels" is deselected.

What I expect: a stereo signal on channels 1+2 on the soundcard, i.e. Soundflower channel 1(2) should transmit on Firewire channel 1(2)

Actual result: I now get the same signal (left and right speaker combined) on ALL of the 12 output channels on the soundcard.

These tests make me believe that the problem is with soundflower, or rather with the combination soundflower + the external soundcard:

- The soundcard works as expected when I use it with other software, e.g. the DJ software Maschine (16 out channels)  from Native Instruments - any software channel can be assigned to any of the channels on the soundcard, and then the signal transmits on that channel only.
- If I select "Built-In Output" as output for Soundflower, I get a stereo signal on the computers headphone jack, as expected.
- If I skip Soundflower and select the external soundcard to be the computer out, the stereo signal transmits on channels 1 + 2 as expected.

My computer:

- MacBook Pro 2.53 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- 4 GB 1076 MHz DDR3
- Mac OS X 10.6.8

The soundcard is built into an Ecler EVO 5 DJ mixer: EVO5 v1.14r10 (1.14.02.08)